# Ubuntu 16.04 – Disable internal WIFI while enabling external WIFI adapter

Tags: network-manager

I’m using a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04, on an LG laptop which is quite old.
In order to get a faster  wifi connection I use an external USB wifi dongle.
Since I do not need both wifis- I wish to turn off on board wifi.

Tries:

1. Turning it off using Ubntu’s network menu – does not remain OFF after boot.
2. Using Laptop physical wifi’s On/Off button, shuts down BOTH wifis.

Is there a more elegant way making this work, other than running a bash script at boot to disable it using `nmcli` ?

at can see upper wifi network disabled(on board ) and lower, connected ( via USB adapter )[image: screencapture]

> Problem solved: After applying @pa4080 answer- device not managed  [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two possible ways to disable any network adaptor/interface at system startup. First, as @TunanGuo [says](https://askubuntu.com/a/964137/566421), use the command `ifconfig` to find the name of your interface. When the interface is disabled you can use `ifconfig -a` to list all interfaces. Let's assume the interface name is **`wlx99wifi`**.

---

**First method.** Edit `/etc/rc.local` with root privileges (use `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` or `sudo -i gedit /etc/rc.local`) and add the following line before the last line in that file, which is `exit 0`:

```
/sbin/ifconfig wlx99wifi down
```

On the next reboot the device will be disabled.

---

**Second method.** This method should be more correct. Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` with root privileges (use `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` or `sudo -i gedit ...`) and add the following line to the bottom of this file:

```
iface wlx99wifi inet manual
```

On the next reboot the device will be disabled. You can run the next command to restart `network-manager` and reload the settings without reboot:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

---

**Create custom shortcuts to up/down the interface.** First install `gksu` package to get a GUI prompt to enter your password when you need to gain root privileges:

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

Then go to `System Settings` → `Keyboard` → `Shortcuts` → `Custom Shortcuts` and:

- Create *Interface UP* shortcut: Click **<kbd>+</kbd>** to add a new keyboard shortcut.

  For *Name* fill **wlx99wifi UP**, and for *Command* fill:

  ```
  gksu ifconfig wlx99wifi up
  ```

  Click *Apply* and then click on the *Disabled* label to assign shortcut key combination. For example, use the combination <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+**<kbd>↑ Arrow Up</kbd>**
- Create *Interface DOWN* shortcut: Click **<kbd>+</kbd>** to add a new keyboard shortcut.

  For *Name* fill **wlx99wifi DOWN**, and for *Command* fill:

  ```
  gksu ifconfig wlx99wifi down
  ```

  Click *Apply* and then click on the *Disabled* label to assign shortcut key combination. For example, use the combination <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+**<kbd>↓ Arrow Down</kbd>**

---

References and sources:

- [Remove network interface permanently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624396/remove-network-interface-permanently)
- [How do I set a custom keyboard shortcut to control volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181341/how-do-i-set-a-custom-keyboard-shortcut-to-control-volume)
- [How do I add sudo commands to a keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/821919/how-do-i-add-sudo-commands-to-a-keyboard-shortcut)
- Author's notes: [Configure WiFi Connections](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-wifi-connections) | [GnomeDev nmcli](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/nmcli.html)

Comment: thank you- second method was applied successfully. screen shot added to witness that "device not managed"

Comment: Hi - I want to try Second method on fedora but I am not able to find [/etc/network/interfaces] . Please help.

Comment: Hi, @Triven, I've never used Fedora.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ifconfig` to control the interfaces. You can type `ifconfig` into terminal.

Both your WiFi cards would pop up as "wlan0" or "wlan1" or other names. Shut down the interface using `ifconfig wlan0 down`. If you found that you shut down the wrong one, use `ifconfig wlan0 up` to enable it. 
You need root privilege to do this, so use `sudo ifconfig ...`

Comment: Your suggestion indeed turned off on board wifi, BUT after reboot it came back on- and I seek for a solution ( if any ) without script at boot

Comment: @Guy.D: It's not exactly scripting, you can edit `/etc/rc.local` to add `ifconfig INTERFACE-NAME down`, before the last line, which is `exit 0`.

Comment: Have you tried to disable the WiFi in the bios, that won't affect an external device!  It may shut down your Bluetooth too - if they are on the same radio.

Comment: @KenMollerup - There is no disable wifi at bios :(