# How to remove virbr0 and virbr0-nic from ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, interface

I have Ubuntu server on my virtual box and all of a sudden I have 2 new interfaces "virbr0" and "virbr0-nic" and I would like to remove them.
(I dont have virt-manager installed on the machine)

it would be amazing if you could help me
Thank you very much.

Comment: [This might do what you need](https://askubuntu.com/a/624555/1222991) 

Comment: But you did get those by installing the `libvirt` service; that's the only one that creates those devices :-P

Comment: thats the funny part i did not install this